# The datatable is not mapping in the datagridview

Tags: c#

```
 {    
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Sure", "Some Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            dt = dsSource.Tables[Index];
            dt.Reset();
            Excel.Workbook workbook;
            Excel.Worksheet NwSheet;
            Excel.Range ShtRange;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelObj = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            OpenFileDialog filedlgExcel = new OpenFileDialog();
            filedlgExcel.Title = "Select file";
            filedlgExcel.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
            //filedlgExcel.FileName = textBox1.Text;
            filedlgExcel.Filter = "Excel Sheet(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
            filedlgExcel.FilterIndex = 1;
            filedlgExcel.RestoreDirectory = true;
            if (filedlgExcel.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            workbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(filedlgExcel.FileName, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                 Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                 Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            NwSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);
            ShtRange = NwSheet.UsedRange;
            for (int Cnum = 1; Cnum <= ShtRange.Columns.Count; Cnum++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn((ShtRange.Cells[1, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString()));
            }
            dt.AcceptChanges();
            string[] columnNames = new String[dt.Columns.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                columnNames[0] = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            }
            //string[] columnNames = (from dc in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>() select dc.ColumnName).ToArray();


            for (int Rnum = 2; Rnum <= ShtRange.Rows.Count; Rnum++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int Cnum = 1; Cnum <= ShtRange.Columns.Count; Cnum++)
                {
                    if ((ShtRange.Cells[Rnum, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2 != null)
                    {
                        dr[Cnum - 1] = (ShtRange.Cells[Rnum, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
                    }
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                dt.AcceptChanges();
            }
            workbook.Close(true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            ExcelObj.Quit();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;                   

}
```

This is the code i am using to fetch excel data into datagridview. It is written on the button click. The first time when the button is clicked the action performed is perfect, the data is shown in the datagridview but if i try it again only column name appears but no data its shows single row with blank data. I debugged the code and found that data is entering into datatable(dt) but the problem is somewhere when it maps to the datagridview. On this line

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

What should i do to resolve this

Comment: add dataGridView1.DataBind(); as well.

Comment: i tried it that doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*** EDIT ***

The problem is that when you clear a DataTable, it only removes the Rows. In order to remove the columns you need to do this :-

```
dt.Columns.Clear();
```

`dt.Reset()`  won't remove data, it just discards all changes.

Each and every time you call this event on button click, you need to remove the previous rows & columns held in the DataTable.

The below code worked fine for me:-

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dt.Columns.Clear();
            dt.Rows.Clear();


            Excel.Workbook workbook;
            Excel.Worksheet NwSheet;
            Excel.Range ShtRange;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelObj = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            OpenFileDialog filedlgExcel = new OpenFileDialog();
            filedlgExcel.Title = "Select file";
            filedlgExcel.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";

            filedlgExcel.Filter = "Excel Sheet(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
            filedlgExcel.FilterIndex = 1;
            filedlgExcel.RestoreDirectory = true;
            if (filedlgExcel.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                workbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(filedlgExcel.FileName, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                 Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                 Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

                NwSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);
                ShtRange = NwSheet.UsedRange;
                for (int Cnum = 1; Cnum <= ShtRange.Columns.Count; Cnum++)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn((ShtRange.Cells[1, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString()));
                }
                dt.AcceptChanges();
                string[] columnNames = new String[dt.Columns.Count];
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    columnNames[0] = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                }
                //string[] columnNames = (from dc in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>() select dc.ColumnName).ToArray();


                for (int Rnum = 2; Rnum <= ShtRange.Rows.Count; Rnum++)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    for (int Cnum = 1; Cnum <= ShtRange.Columns.Count; Cnum++)
                    {
                        if ((ShtRange.Cells[Rnum, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2 != null)
                        {
                            dr[Cnum - 1] = (ShtRange.Cells[Rnum, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    dt.AcceptChanges();
                }
                workbook.Close(true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                ExcelObj.Quit();

                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;   
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: No it is not working same issue. First time it is importing successfully but when importing second time only column names no rows

Comment: Then your DataTable is incorrect, and that is what you need to look at.

Comment: I m getting data into data table and if datatable is incorrect then how it is showing when the task is performed first

Comment: I'll get back to you. I will attempt to replicate your program.